# How can I get my website to scale properly when resized?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a:hover,
a:link,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.main-content {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  background: black;
}

.header-container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom, .right {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
}

.right {
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 56px;
  right: 0;
}

.bottom {
  left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 3.5vh;
  bottom: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 10%;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 90%;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 8888;
    transition: height .3s .1s ease;
  }
}
.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: space-evenly;
    height: 80%;
    /*
      Initially list will be hidden and will reappear once the
      nav-bar is opened
    */
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  }
}
.nav-list-item {
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  right: 75.5vw;
  left: -23.5vw;
  transition: color .3s ease;
  color: #989797;
}

.nav-list-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 99px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  a {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .nav-list-item {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #989797;
    width: 80%;
    justify-content: left;
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
}
.sub-list-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* If we need show/hide feature */
  height: inherit;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sub-list-container {
    display: none;
  }
}
.sub-list {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}

.sub-item {
  color: #989797;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  align-self: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}

.sub-item:hover {
  color: white;
}

.sub-item::before {
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-list-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.nav-list-item:hover .sub-list-container {
  /* For show/hide feature */
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.toggle-nav {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-nav-off {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .toggle-nav {
    display: block;
  }

  .toggle-nav-off {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
  }

  :target {
    /* Defining the height of the shutter effect */
    height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  }

  :target .nav-list {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility .2s .2s ease, opacity .2s .2s ease;
  }
}
/* Code for the side-bar starts here */
.side-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  /* Initial width according to size of image */
  height: calc(100% - 56px);
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Imp to give as the List is having width larger than the initial width of the side-bar */
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 8vw;
}

.side-bar-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    /* Initial width according to size of image */
    height: calc(100% - 56px);
    background: black;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Imp to give as the List is having width larger than the initial width of the side-bar */
    transition: all .3s ease;
    width: 250px;
  }


.item-list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 250px;
  left: -3.2vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;
  padding: 3.85vh .3vw;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: relative;
  color: #989797;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.item #dribble, .item #behance, .item #flickr {
  width: 3.5vw;
  height: 7vh;
}

.item #instagram {
  width: 3vw;
  height: 6vh;
  margin-left: .5vw;
}
.item #etsy {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 7vh;
  margin-left: -2.1vw;
}

.item #behance {
  margin-left: .3vw;
}

.item #flickr{
  margin-left: -.5vw;
}

.item #dribble {
  margin-left: .2vw;
}
.item #pinterest {
  width: 3.5vw;
  height: 7vh;
  margin-left: .4vw;
}

/* Code for the HOVER effect on the list items */
.item::before {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  width: 3px;
  transition: transform .2s ease, width .3s .2s ease;
}

.sub-item::before {
  width: 0px;
  transition: transform .1s ease, width .2s .1s ease;
}

.item::before,
.sub-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff506e, black);
  z-index: -1;
}

.item:hover::before {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.item:hover::before,
.sub-item:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.active {
  color: #989797;
  /* background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff506e, black); THIS MAKES THE FIRST BUTTON ALWAYS RED AND HIGHLIGHTED, WHICH WE DON'T WANT */
}

.nav-active {
  color: 989797;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(200deg, 50%, 92%);
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.modal-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background: url("https://37.media.tumblr.com/53fc4e7e4096cba63c0133167a4b6168/tumblr_n33ukkyWLN1rwhqloo1_500.gif");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.toggle-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 1.4vw;
}

/* Opening modal using CSS */
:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

:target .modal-item {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}


/* .container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: white;
    
} */

.iframe {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -41.98vw;
  top:52.09vh;
  height: 92.322vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: black;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>"Users folio"</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="logo">
          <!-- COMPANY LOGO GOES HERE -->
      </div>
      <nav class="nav-bar" id="nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="nav-list-item nav-active">Home</li>
          <li class="nav-list-item">
            About
            <div class="sub-list-container">
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li class="sub-item">About Our Company</li>
                <li class="sub-item">Our Mission</li>
                <li class="sub-item">Happy Clients</li>
                <li class="sub-item">Team</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-list-item">
            <a href="#modal-item">Instructions</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="toggle-nav-off">
          <a href="#"><img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/1157/PNG/512/1487086345-cross_81577.png" alt="Close Icon" width="30" height="30"></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="toggle-nav">
        <a href="#nav"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/menu-elements/154/menu-round-512.png" alt="Close Icon" width="30" height="30"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- 
                Currently just researching which sites are able to have their x-options
                        bypassed in order to allow viewing within an iframe, so disregard the iframe source. 
        -->
        <iframe class="iframe" name="change-website" src="https://www.etsy.com"></iframe>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="side-bar">
    <ul class="item-list">
      <li class="item active"><a href="https://www.behance.net" target="change-website"><img id="behance" src="images/behance.png" width="50" height="50" class="item-img" />Behance</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="https://www.dribbble.com" target="change-website"><img id="dribble" src="images/dribble3.png" width="50" height="50" class="item-img" />Dribble</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="https://www.etsy.com" target="change-website"><img id="etsy" src="images/etsy11.png" width="50" height="50" class="item-img"/>Etsy</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="https://www.flickr.com" target="change-website"><img id="flickr" src="images/flick2.png" width="50" height="50" class="item-img" />Flickr</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/onwheez" target="change-website"><img id="instagram" src="images/Instagram_AppIcon_Aug2017.png" width="50" height="50" class="item-img" />Instagram</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com" target="change-website"><img id="pinterest" src="images/pinterest3.png" width="50" height="50" class="item-img" />Pinterest</a></li>
      <!-- <li class="item"><a href="https://www.twitch.com/twitchpresents" target="change-website"><img id="flickr" src="images/twitch3.png" width="50" height="50" class="item-img"/>Twitch</a></li> -->
      
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="left-side-bar">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
      <div class="modal" id="modal-item">
        <div class="modal-item">
          <div class="toggle-modal">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/1157/PNG/512/1487086345-cross_81577.png" alt="Close Icon" width="30" height="30"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>



  
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts.js">
</body>

</html>
```

So I know that I need to use media queries to properly scale and put the code into different media queries for each max width ect.

Here is the code I have been working with, but when I change the size, even when I have tried to put them into different media queries and code them to that scale when I change the browser size, I still get issues where things like my iframe and the top menu bar moving and not being in the correct place.

I am still pretty new to frontend but I was just curious what I may be able to do to fix this?

When the browser resizes, everything should stay in its correct place. 
The Home, About and Instructions should be starting from above the iframe and slightly past the top left of the iframe

Comment: The problem is in the css you should be using % instead of px this way the proportions will stay the same whatever screen size you have. For exemple in .modal-item  you have forced a width: 500px; instead try using a percentage like 130%

Comment: I also use VH and VW, do you think it would be wise to change these to % as well?

I just found that using that versus pixels was easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking a look at your code, it's seen that you missed a meta tag to make your website resizable, add it on your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This should fix your issue.